# Third Party Vendors for MagSafe 3 Accessories

Tags: magsafe

Tried searching through Amazon, but I don't seem to be able to find third suppliers of MagSafe 3 accessories. Things like USB-C to MagSafe 3 cables, USB-C to MagSafe 3 adapters.

Comment: I would bet there aren't any. Did you just see that recently there was a firmware upgrade for Apple's own USB-C to MagSafe cable? That would indicate to me there is a *lot* more than just wires there. Granted USB-C has some active elements but a *firmware upgrade for a cable?* I would bet there is little opportunity for 3rd party manufacturers to make any money there.

Comment: Not in the cable but in the nine cubic inches of adapter on the mains end of the cable.  https://www.macworld.com/article/1514105/macbook-air-pro-magsafe-cable-firmware-update.html